# Magento 2.3.1: Billing / Shipping Address Zip Code Automatically Removes Leading 0's

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, shipping-address, billing-address

We have an issue where the Billing / Shipping addresses on an order will automatically remove the leading 0 from a zip code. For example:

`Danbury, Connecticut, 06811` becomes `Danbury, Connecticut, 6811`

This causes some validation errors with UPS and other shipping API's as it is trying to validate `6811` as a zip code.

So how can we make it so billing / shipping saves the full zip code with a leading zero?

Comment: Same problem here with Magento 2.4.4